# How can I used diff and sed

Tags: regex, bash, cygwin, diff

What I need to do is diff 2 files to check for changes. However both of these files have a certain 4 lines in them that are guaranteed to change and that I want to ignore for the diff. My idea is to use sed to remove the 4 lines using a regex which I can get to work no problem, however I must not be using the sed command right in the diff as I get the error "The system cannot find the file specified".

The sed command I'm using is:

```
sed "/regex1/,/regex2/ d" "filename"
```

This removes the 4 lines between the two regex's properly.

The diff command I'm trying is:

```
diff <(sed "/regex1/,/regex2/ d" "file1") <(sed "/regex1/,/regex2/ d" "file2")
```

and this is giving the error.

Can anybody tell me how I'm using diff wrong?

Thanks

Comment: What is the error that you're getting?

Comment: "The system cannot find the file specified".

Comment: It sounds like "grep -v" would be a better way to remove those 4 lines, and then you can do "diff" for the entire file. If you post your file contents, we can help more.

Comment: Works for me as shown.  Can you give the WHOLE error message so we can figure out where it is coming from?  If I fiddle with the filenames I get `No such file or directory`, the message you got is Windows specific.

Comment: Process substitution is a bash feature, so make sure you're not running your script with /bin/sh

Answer (score 1):

I didn't have problem running the command you tried.

However I could use the command

`sed ... | diff - <(sed ...)`

with the same results